# Get name of cluster release pipeline is targeting on manual intervention job

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm currently attempting to create a release pipeline to a service fabric cluster.

The goal of the pipeline is to take a built artefact and publish it to a service fabric cluster which it does successfully.

I am looking to add in a manual intervention step which will notify the user of the name of the SF cluster they are attempting to deploy to.

How can I do this? there does not seem to be a way to access the name of the cluster. using the predefined variable

```
 $(Parameters.serviceConnectionName)
```

Will print the ID of the connection, rather than its actual name

Comment: Hi @MantyQuestions, how are things going? Is my suggestion helpful to you? Please have a try with. Any update, feel free to tell us. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> using the predefined variable
> $(Parameters.serviceConnectionName)
> Will print the ID of the connection, rather than its actual name

I do not see any predefined variable that named "**Parameters.serviceConnectionName**" in the following documentations about Azure DevOps. Where did you find this variable?

- [**Use predefined variables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
- [**Classic release and artifacts variables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch)

To get the name of service fabric cluster, maybe you can try to check if there is any specific command-line or API on the service fabric. If yes, you can run the related command-line or API and get the service fabric cluster from the output.

Comment: My mistake, $(Parameters.serviceConnectionName) is not a predfined variable, it is relevant to the service fabric deploy job. While there is an API that we can get the cluster name from the service connection, I am unable to pass a value from a powershell script to the manual intervention job as it is an agentless job, and i cannot make it dependant on a script or find any other way to pass values from a powershell script to the manual intervention job.

Comment: Maybe, you can try using the [YAML pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema) to set up your deployment pipeline.